# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\log.php on line 18

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

  $connect= new mysqli('localhost', 'root','' ,'prueba2');

  if($connect->connect_error){
    die('connection failed');
  }else {
    echo 'connection worked';
  }

  $username= $_POST['username'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];

  $sql="SELECT name FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND 
  password='$password'";

  $result= $connect->query($sql);

  if($result-> num_rows> 0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<br>Admin name is: " . $row["name"];
    }
  } else {
    echo "<br>Username and password dont match";
  }

?>
```

I dont know why i have this error, im trying to do a simple login to try a SQL injection, pls help me its from a homework, dont close the post saying its a duplicate help me pls!

This is the Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\log.php on line 18

Comment: El código es correcto y debería funcionar. Yo creo que el campo "name" no lo tienes en tu bbdd. Sólo te falta la clave de la bbdd pero no te daría ese error, te devolvería algo como "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' ".

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿porqué poner un "while"? ¿Esperas obtener más de 1 resultado? Con poner '$row=$result->fetch_assoc();' dentro del if, tendrías suficiente.

Comment: Cuál es la línea 18? ¿Viste que tienes un espacio de más en `$result-> num_rows`?